# valueForKey on data NSManagedObject not releasing memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management

I want to deal with a data attribute, named `originalImage` in every `Media` entity in the store.

The problem is that despite the autoreleasing, memory builds up every time it's accessed via `valueForKey`, and eventually the app crashes. Or perhaps it's loading large individual NSData items which is the problem, but Instruments shows it to be a steadily inclining graph of memory usage, until it eventually gives me a memory warning and then crashes.

I haven't started on the rest of the code for this yet, so i'm not performing some hidden task that i'm not showing you.

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Media"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:10];
    NSArray *mediaItems = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];


    for (NSManagedObject *media in mediaItems) {

        @autoreleasepool {

            [media valueForKey:@"originalImage"];

        }

    }
```

EDIT: Today it seems that even just mentioning the NSManagedObject media is enough to cause this media leak. So even without the valueForKey line, i have a leak. I've tried this:

```
    while (i < count) {
        @autoreleasepool {
        NSManagedObject *media = [mediaItems objectAtIndex:i];

            [[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:media mergeChanges:NO];

        NSLog(@"i: %i", i);
        i++;
        }
    }
```

This also didn't work, and crashed at the same point.

Comment: This is a complete shot in the dark; but does turning the `media` object back to a fault in the inner loop have any impact on memory footprint?  e.g. `[[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:media] mergeChanges:NO]`

Comment: This seems to be a variation (if not a duplicate) of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545346/accessing-data-attribute-of-nsmanagedobject-gives-me-memory-issues. You could at least add put a reference to that one in this question, so that people who try to help you know what already has been said on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<[mediaItems count]; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSManagedObject *media = [mediaItems objectAtIndex:i];
        [media valueForKey:@"originalImage"];
    }
}
```

Maybe this way "media" gets released properly at every loop.

(Sorry, I put this on a comment. I'm new on SO and not enough rep.)

Comment: Could you use Instruments to see if is something of a concrete object "media" of the array (maybe one too large to handle, even individually)?